# Limit in db query returns wrong amount for certain values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, limit, ruby-on-rails-4

If I do this:

```
@open_shops = Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening_times.day =?", today)
              .order("opening_times.opens+opening_times.open_for")
```

@open_shops.size returns 10

If I do this:

```
@open_shops = Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening_times.day =?", today)
              .order("opening_times.opens+opening_times.open_for")
              .limit(2)
```

@open_shops.size returns 2, as expected. .limit(1) also works as expected.

But if I do this:

```
@open_shops = Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening_times.day =?", today)
              .order("opening_times.opens+opening_times.open_for")
              .limit(3)
```

@open_shops.size returns 2! As you can see above, 10 records are returned when there is no limit, but only 2 are returned with a limit of 3. With any limit from 3-10, it returns one less than it should. My mind is boggling.

Removing the where statement or the order statement makes limit work as expected.

EDIT: Perhaps worth noting that it isn't the same record missing each time. It's always the last one on the list that is missing. So limit(3) returns exactly the results that limit(2) should return for example.

These are my models:

```
class Shop
  has_many :opening_times
end

class OpeningTime
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

Comment: Open the console and enter the same query with to_sql at the end.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks for the nice debugging tip! With limit(3), it returns `"SELECT  \"shops\".* FROM \"shops\"  WHERE (opening_times.day =6)  ORDER BY opening_times.opens+opening_times.open_for LIMIT 3"`.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but is that SQL what you expect? Shouldn't there a JOIN in there for the opening_times table?

Comment: @chucknelson According to the docs, includes doesn't use a join table. Thanks for the idea though. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Ah, just tried it in my console and it does join behind the scenes - thanks! Just FYI, apparently the "correct"/non-deprecated way to do these types of queries is now: `@open_shops = Shop.includes(:opening_times).where("opening_times.day =?", today).references(:opening_times)`. Sorry I still don't know why you're having this strange problem :-/

Comment: Same problem here. I solved it by using `joins` instead of `includes`. But `joins` doesn't solve the N+1 Query issue and combining `Shop.joins(:opening_times).includes(:opening_times)` doesn't work either. I have the feeling we can call it a bug! @chucknelson do you have references for `#references` method? Raises an error for me...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether this might help or not at this point, or whether this was your actual problem but one case where `limit(n)` returns less than `n` records even if the expression being limited has `n` or more records is when you have a counter cache incorrectly set.

For example,

```
class ParentThing
  has_many :children_things
end

class ChildrenThing
  belongs_to :parent_thing
end
```

In this case, with parent_things table having a `children_thing_count` column,

```
ParentThing.find(1).children_things.size
```

will return whatever (correct or incorrect) it is in the `children_thing_count` column whereas

```
ParentThing.find(1).children_things.limit(n).size
```

will always return the correct count expression over the table with the counter.

So, *be very careful with counter cache's*!!

Answer (score 0):

Well.  I had one shop that is closed all day on Saturday (the day I was querying for). I began to wonder if this record was acting as a "ghost" getting included in the query (even though it shouldn't) without actually returning. This would explain why the last record of each query was missing, because the ghost record was knocking it off the list.

So I tried making a dummy opening time for this shop. I had it open at 00:01 and stay open for one minute. Suddenly, everything worked! If that isn't already weird enough, I then deleted this dummy record, and it *still* worked.

I'm not accepting my own answer out of hope that someone can explain what on earth happened. At this point, demon possession and witchcraft appear like reasonable explanations.